# writing a header with 125,000+ columns and two rows

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Excel limits the columns of any csv file around 3000. I am trying to write 125,000 columns in the following format:

- O1
- MA1
- MI1
- C1
- V1
- ...
- O125000
- MA125000
- MI125000
- C125000
- V125000

```
import pandas as pd
def formatting(i):
    return tuple(map(lambda x: x+str(i), ("O", "MA", "MI", "C", "V")))
l = []
for i in range(1, 125001):
    l.extend(formatting(i))
f = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
f.columns = l
f.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```

I tried coding this script but its too slow and inconsistent in the fact that its prone to errors. However, you can get the idea of what I am trying to do from this script.

The current script I use to generate a csv(that contains 2 rows and 125,000+ columns) is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

allfiles = glob.glob('*.csv')
index = 0

def testing(file):
    #file = file.loc[:,'Open':'Volume']
    file = file.values.reshape(1, -1)
    return file


for _fileT in allfiles:
    nFile = pd.read_csv(_fileT, header=0, usecols=range(1,6))
    fFile = testing(nFile)
    df = pd.DataFrame(fFile)
    new_df = df.iloc[:125279]
    new_df = new_df.shift(1, axis=1)
    new_df.to_csv('HeadCSV/FinalCSV.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=0)
```

This script reads two csv files in the directory, and aggregates them into one file however how can I make sure that it prints the header mentioned above and labels the two rows it prints out?

Id basically like to combine these two scripts in the most logical way possible.

the idea is to write the header, then get all the data from the files into the dataframe, then do the row indexing as mentioned, and finally throw it all into a CSV

Comment: To clarify, do both files have the same headers *(the one you pointed in the question)*?

Comment: Those two files don't have any headers. They simply begin at the price

Comment: Gotcha. I am a little confused by your question "[...] how can I make sure that it prints the header mentioned above and labels the two rows it prints out?" What are the two rows?

Comment: The two rows are simply the indexes I'm trying to place in the first column for each file _fileT in allfiles it reads

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want shape `(2, 125k)` instead of `(125k, 2)`